# acts_as_solr returns all rows in the database when using the model as search query

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, lucene, solr

In our application we're using acts_as_solr for search.  Everything seems to be running smoothly except for the fact that using the model name as the search query returns every single row in the table.

For example, let's say we have a users table.  We specify acts_as_solr in our model to search the fields first name, last name and handle   acts_as_solr :fields => [:handle, :lname, :fname].  When you use "user" as the search term it returns every single user in the system, or every row in the database as a result.

Has anyone else run into this?

Comment: That is really interesting. Have you looked at the generated documents that get sent to solr to see where that field is getting included?

Answer (score 1):

This is due to the way acts_as_solr builds the query within parser_methods.rb

There are few changes you will need to make within parser_methods.rb

Change

```
models =  "AND #{solr_configuration[:type_field]}:#self.name}"
```

to

```
models =  "#{solr_configuration[:type_field]}:#self.name}"
```

Then don't include the constructed models string into the query.

```
query = "(#{query.gsub(/ *: */,"_t:")}) #{models}"
```

Change this to just

```
query = "(#{query.gsub(/ *: */,"_t:")})"
```

Now you will need to force the models portion of this query into the search over to SOLR.

I did this with.....

```
query_options[:fq_model] = models
```

Went over to standard.rb

Made sure to add

```
:fq_model
```

into the VALID_PARAMS Array.

Added the following

```
if @params[:fq_model]
 hash["fq"] = @params[:fq_model]
end
```

I added some extra cases but you shouldn't need them if unless you want to make :fq an option on find_by_solr.

After I had these all in place I can now search for the model name and I get the much smaller result set I would expect.

Chances are that multi_solr_search will need updates to work as well since it appears that the type_t portion of the query is hard coded into that method.

Figured most of this out when I ran into some highlighting issues related to this question.
[Highlighting in Solr 1.4 - requireFieldMatch](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2548750/highlighting-in-solr-1-4-requirefieldmatch)